# Save Canvas Image data to mySQL database and retrieve it to edit again

Tags: html, draw

Let say I draw a line on a DIV, using Jquery library

I want to save the line into database, how I can do it?

```
function save()
        {
          var c = document.getElementById("colors_sketch");
          var ctx= c.getContext("2d");
          var data = ctx.getImageData(0,0,c.width,c.height);
        }
```

I manage to get the var data from getImageData() method, how can I save it to mySQL database?

I want to retrieve the image some other day and edit the drawing, like draw extra line, how can I do it?

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now only i saw this post i got success for storing and retrieving the canvas images using the following references. You need to convert the canvas to image format and the save i to databse.

[Create The canvas](http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/#require-drawn)

[Store the canvas image into mysql DB](http://thomasjbradley.ca/articles/saving-signatures-php-mysql/)